# Calculate a mode for multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like to calculate a mode for multiple columns in the same time in Spark and use this calculated values to impute missings in a DataFrame. I found how to calculate e.g. a mean, but a mode is more complex I think.

Here is a mean calculation:

```
val multiple_mean = df.na.fill(df.columns.zip(
  df.select(intVars.map(mean(_)): _*).first.toSeq
).toMap)
```

I am able to calculate a mode in brute force way:

```
var list = ArrayBuffer.empty[Float]

for(column <- df.columns){
  list += df.select(column).groupBy(col(column)).count().orderBy(desc("count")).first.toSeq(0).asInstanceOf[Float]
}

val multiple_mode = df.na.fill(df.columns.zip(list.toSeq).toMap)
```

What way would be the best if we consider a performance?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use UserDefinedAggregateFunction. The code below is tested in spark 1.6.2

First create a class which extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

class ModeUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction{

  override def dataType: DataType = StringType

  override def inputSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("input", StringType)

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("mode", MapType(StringType, LongType))

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = Map.empty[Any, Long]
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val buff0 = buffer.getMap[Any, Long](0)
    val inp = input.get(0)
    buffer(0) = buff0.updated(inp, buff0.getOrElse(inp, 0L) + 1L)
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    val mp1 = buffer1.getMap[Any, Long](0)
    val mp2 = buffer2.getMap[Any, Long](0)

    buffer1(0) = mp1 ++ mp2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + mp1.getOrElse(k, 0L)) }
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    lazy val st = buffer.getMap[Any, Long](0).toStream
    val mode = st.foldLeft(st.head){case (e, s) => if (s._2 > e._2) s else e}
    mode._1
  }

}
```

Afterwords you could use it with your dataframe in the following manner.

```
val modeColumnList = List("some", "column", "names") // or df.columns.toList
val modeAgg = new ModeUDAF()
val aggCols = modeColumnList.map(c => modeAgg(df(c)))
val aggregatedModeDF = df.agg(aggCols.head, aggCols.tail: _*)
aggregatedModeDF.show()
```

Also you could use .collect on the final dataframe to collect the result in a scala data structure.

**Note**: The performance of this solution depends on the cardinality of the input column.

Comment: Thanks, I see it's only resonable when cardinality is low. I try this on my generated data where each category has only 1,2,3 values and this method was very slow.